# submit and foreach ajax data multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, foreach

**First:** I was able to successfully pass **1 array** to PHP via AJAX with the following:

### Successful example

```
// Basic HTML Form
// (with sample inputs & values)
// ------------------------------

<form method="post" id="unitDataForm" >
    <!-- sample 1 -->
        <input type="text" name="seqImg[]" value="111" />
        <textarea name="seqDesc[]" />sample 1</textarea>
    <!-- sample 2 -->
        <input type="text" name="seqImg[]" value="222" />
        <textarea name="seqDesc[]" />sample 2</textarea>
</form>

// Script for sending a single array
// ---------------------------------

        var seqImg = new Array();
            $('input[name="seqImg[]"]').each( function() {
            seqImg.push($(this).val());
        } );

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test_form_process2.php',
            data: {seqImg:seqImg},
            cache: false,
            async: false
        })

// The PHP...
// -----------------

//...config with $dbc...validation & error testing...

if(!empty($_POST["seqImg"])) {

    $seqImgs = $_POST['seqImg'];
    $seqArray = $seqImgs;
    $sql= "INSERT INTO  unit_test(`unit_id`,`seq_img`) VALUES ";    
        $i=0;
        $seqArray_count = count($seqArray);
        foreach($seqImgs as $seqImg) {
            $seqImg = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $seqImg);
            $end = ($i == $seqImgs_count-1) ? ';' : ',';
            $sql .= "('".$unit_id1."','".$seqImg."')".$end;
            $i++;
```

The above is working fine (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/gc6qq8j4/) )...except...I'd like to submit through the seq_desc[] in this POST as well. I've tried a few examples I've found, but I'm not 100% how to `submit/attach` *in ajax* & then `foreach` the additional array *in php*.

## Current Attempt (not working):

```
// added the seqDesc input
var seqDesc = new Array();
$('textarea[name="seqDesc[]"]').each( function() {
    seqDesc.push($(this).val());
    } );

// and updated the ajax data to:
    data: {seqImg:seqImg,seqDesc:seqDesc},

// The php
// --------
// added 
$seqDesc=$_POST['seqDesc'];
$seqArray = array_combine($seqImgs,$seqDescs);
foreach($seqArray as $seqImg=>$seqDesc) {
```

At present, I'm getting `[]` in the console...

Comment: Have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: @Darren Thanks for that. Although this didn't change anything, it actually made me realise I'd made a very simple LOGIC error. Seeing the `[]` in the console log, I'd realised my if(!empty){}else{} logic in my php happened to be backwards. I just had to reverse `if(!empty)...` to `if(empty)...`. My submit and receive is actually working perfectly fine now.

Comment: Always the simple ones that mess us around ;-) glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all of the submit/receive coding is working fine above. The problem was in my LOGIC (if/else) statement...

Seeing the `[]` in the console log, I'd realised my `if(!empty){}else{}` logic in my php happened to be backwards. I just had to reverse `if(!empty)...` to `if(empty)....`

```
if(empty($_POST["seqImg"])
    && empty($_POST['seqDesc']) ) { }else {
```